# How do i populate <select>tag with databse values?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, database, html-select

I have one select tag in my html page which is used to identify different categories.So currently am hard coding that category inside html page.like below

```
<tr>
<td>
<select name="category">
<option name="options">Fasfood
<option name="options">Restaurante</option>
<option name="options">Cafenele</option>
<option name="options">Baruri</option>
<option name="options">Cluburi</option>
<option name="options">Pub-uri</option>
<option name="options">Pizzerii</option>
</td>
</tr>
```

instead of these value i have a db with a table called "categories" and inside that 2 fields "id" and "name" id is just a auto increment number and "name"id the category name. i need to populate that contents into this select tag.Please help me

Comment: You've tagged this JavaScript, so pick a server side JavaScript implementation, find a MySQL library for JS to interact with that database and have a go.

Comment: Are you using a scripting language like php?  jquery libraries? Anything?

Comment: i have to use javascript for this

Comment: no ,its like when i load this page i will call one javascript function and from that i will take db contents through JSON then parse and populate into select tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an object oriented approach:

```
$categories = $query->my_categories();
foreach ( $categories as $category )
{
    echo "<option value='".$category->id."'>".$category-> category_name."</option>";
}
```

otherwise, a while loop like such :

```
<?php $q = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = mysqli_query($q) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['field1']; ?>"><?php echo $row['field1']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ok i will try that and let you know the result, I can add your second code(php) to my html file ryt?

Comment: Given you change the values "categories" and "field1" to reflect your db structure, the code is ready to use. Then again note that if you're using mysql rather than mysqli, the query would be `$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories", $mysql);`

Comment: -1: HTML requires encoding, you can not just put database values into HTML verbatim.

Comment: @hakre I have not covered this due to the fact that the encoding could be from various sources, and therefor the solution proposed assumes that encoding has been set somehow. Also, the question does not ask about encoding, therefore it was unrelated, thus omitted.

Comment: Bla Bla Bla :) Take an extra focus on correct output, esp. encoding when you answer noob users, it's important. Otherwise your answer is of not much help, the user thinks it works and runs away with it, but the code is just inherently flawed. And `$mysqli` in your non-OOP part of the answer is actually an object of type `mysqli`.

Comment: thanks it works very well!